# Linux on Dex - Can you install additional programs? R? Vim?

Tags: applications, samsung, installation, linux

Linux on Dex is on an Arm processor, not Intel processor. Does this mean I can't install most *normal* programs? If you have Linux on Dex could you try and install these two programs, run them, and confirm this will work? I know it just came out, but would like to know before laying out a grand on a Samsung Galaxy Note 9.

[R Statistical Package](https://cran.r-project.org/)

```
apt-get update
apt-get install r-base
R
```

[Vim Editor](https://www.vim.org/download.php#others)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vim
vim new_project.c
```

*And to quit Vim press `Esc` then press `:`. The cursor should appear at the lower left corner of the screen beside a colon prompt. Enter the following `q!` and Vim will quit.*

Comment: Just read what it says [on their website](https://www.linuxondex.com/). Quoting: "packages (apps and programs) must be built for ARM 64-bit and must comply with [Android security policy](https://source.android.com/security/selinux/)". I see no further restrictions. So if there are builds of r and vim available meeting those conditions, they should run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of these Linux packages load and run fine on Dex (Note 9):

R:
[image]

vim:
[image]

Comment: That's great news! Is there anyway to reach you offline so we can trade some notes on *Linux on Dex*?

Comment: As long as an app has an ARM compiled project then it should run just fine on Note 9. Lots of apps however aren't compiled for ARM. So you'll either need to compile them yourself to ARM or you'll need to contact the developers and ask them to compile it for ARM.

Comment: By the way Linux on DeX has been cancelled by Samsung time ago; before the update to Android 10.